# Use session variables in css

Tags: php, html, css, session, laravel

I have this css code, I'm trying to manage the background of the web page dynamically. To do that I have to use a session variable. Using the session variable, however, does not change anything, or rather, does not set anything. While imposed if a variable in the php file itself works. How can I use the variable outside the file? I'm using Laravel 4.1. Thanks for your help.

Here's the code:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); 
$immagine = Session::get('url_image');
?>
body{ 
    background-image: url("<?php echo $immagine ?>");
    width:  100%;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif !important;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: What does $immagine contain?

Comment: have you looked at the generated css to see what really got output?

Comment: Is the `css` file handled by PHP (does it have the appropriate extension of `*.php`)? Does the `css` file bootstrap your entire Laravel framework (otherwise `Session::get()` will not be available)?

Comment: You might not have access to the class at that point, what if you used an inline `style: background-image: url({{ Session::get('url_image') }} );`? I've used this before and then just styled the rest of the body using css.

Comment: @Naruto $immagine contain the URL of image

Comment: @MarcB If instead of "Session :: get ('url_img')" put directly the URL works well.

Comment: @MihaiStancu Can you explain more please? Sorry but I did not understand

Comment: @francesco: doesn't matter. what does the PHP generate? If the php-built css has `url("")` instead of `url("/foo/kittens.jpg")`, then there's your problem.

Comment: Generates this: "../images/bol.jpg"

Comment: @Francesco your CSS files are not handled by PHP by default. If you have a `*.css` file in which you wrote the PHP code it will not work because PHP will never even attempt to execute that code.

Comment: @Francesco if however you have a `*.php` file which only outputs CSS code then it should work -- but if your PHP file isn't a Laravel action or a Laravel template then it won't have all of the Laravel environment (classes, functions) loaded.

Comment: @Francesco since you say it works and the output is `"../images/bol.jpg"` that means both of the above already work correctly and your current issue is probably something to do with relative paths -- when you use relative paths in CSS they're relative based on the folder in which the CSS file resides.

Comment: It's what I've done, the file I'm using has the css inside but has the extension php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help.

"When people are asked about features they would like to CSS, "variables" always seems to come up. Whether or not this is a good idea is still something I personally haven't decided on, but I'd lean toward yes. Regardless, using PHP, it is trivially easy to use variables in CSS. This is certainly not a new trick, but I've never specifically covered it so I thought I ought to."

http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/